# Get user with most upvotes from Data Explorer

Tags: sql, dataexplorer

I'm trying to find the user with the most upvotes from SE's data explorer: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/105658

```
SELECT
  Users.DisplayName as TheUser,
  COUNT(Votes.Id) as TheUpvotes
FROM
  Votes,
  Users
WHERE
    Votes.VoteTypeId=2
  AND
    Votes.UserId=Users.Id
GROUP BY
  Users.DisplayName
```

This query returns 0 results. I can't figure out why. Can you?

Comment: It is Jon Skeet. You don't need a query for that :)

Comment: @juergend haha - but still, I'd like to see it!

Comment: what do you by most upvote? upvotes receive by user or user has upvoted a question or answer?

Comment: @JW upvotes performed by a user.

Comment: @JW pretty much, if it would be descending ordered by UpVotes. I don't really understand that query, can you explain what it does? And, more important: can you explain why my query doesn't work?

Comment: `UpMod` doesn't mean upvote.

Comment: @JW then what does it mean? Can you make this an answer?

Comment: See the [SE DB doc](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to join some tables. All that you need are found on table `User`.

`UPVOTES` as well as `DOWNVOTES` are anonymous that is why you cannot count it. The value already exist on column `UpVotes` and `DownVotes`

Query

```
SELECT [User Link], UpVotes, rn
FROM
(
  SELECT a.ID as [User Link],
         a.UpVotes,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a.UpVotes DESC) rn
  FROM   Users a
)x
WHERE  rn <= 10
ORDER BY UpVotes DESC
```

Comment: if you want to have parameters, http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/105684